# Easily saving .doc files to another formats programmatically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We're been asked to make it possible to save a .doc file as a pdf file, odt file, doc and .docx file.

Aside from saving it as a doc/docx file, we're kinda stuck at .odt and pdf files. 
I've tried aspose.words and it works great.

But is there any other way to do this without aspose? We'll try to convince our client on buying it but if there's any free or cheaper solution, we're willing to try it.

Comment: If it basically does everything and if you go with it you're done, just take the hourly salary of a developer and show that wasting time with other solutions would be a waste of money.

Comment: Haha 
Can't say looking for a solution for this is getting annoying...;/

Comment: You've found one, it isn't ridiculously expensive, time to move on.

Comment: You could automate Word.  Use the Word object model to save in different formats.  I believe Word supports PDF natively or via a free download.

Comment: Automate Word = Interop class? If it is, it's not a good idea...as far as i know, even Microsoft discourages its use. And we had problems in the past with it.